# Grab values from seperate csv file and replace the values of columns in a pipe delimited file

Tags: python, csv

Trying to whip this out in python. Long story short I got a csv file that contains column data i need to inject into another file that is pipe delimited. My understanding is that python can't replace values, so i have to re-write the whole file with the new values.

data file(csv):
**value1,value2,iwantthisvalue3**

source file(txt, | delimited)
**value1|value2|iwanttoreplacethisvalue3|value4|value5|etc**

fixed file(txt, | delimited)
**samevalue1|samevalue2| replacedvalue3|value4|value5|etc**

I can't figure out how to accomplish this. This is my latest attempt(broken code):

```
import re
import csv

result = []
row = []
with open("C:\data\generatedfixed.csv","r") as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        fields = line.split(',')
        result.append(fields[2])

with open("C:\data\data.txt","r") as source_file, with open("C:\data\data_fixed.txt", "w") as fixed_file:
    for line in source_file:
        fields = line.split('|')
        n=0
        for value in result:
            fields[2] = result[n]
            n=n+1
        row.append(line)
    for value in row
       fixed_file.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) package here, it makes handling tabular data very easy and it would help you a lot in this case. Once you have installed pandas import it with:

```
import pandas as pd
```

To read the files simply use:

```
data_file = pd.read_csv("C:\data\generatedfixed.csv")
source_file = pd.read_csv('C:\data\data.txt', delimiter = "|")
```

and after that manipulating these two files is easy, I'm not exactly sure how many values or which ones you want to replace, but if the length of both "iwantthisvalue3" and "iwanttoreplacethisvalue3" is the same then this should do the trick:

```
source_file['iwanttoreplacethisvalue3'] = data_file['iwantthisvalue3]
```

now all you need to do is save the dataframe (the table that we just updated) into a file, since you want to save it to a .txt file with "|" as the delimiter this is the line to do that (however you can customize how to save it in a lot of ways):

```
source_file.to_csv("C:\data\data_fixed.txt", sep='|', index=False)
```

Let me know if everything works and this helped you. I would also encourage to read up (or watch some videos) on pandas if you're planning to work with tabular data, it is an awesome library with great documentation and functionality.